# c: passing a string to a function failure

Tags: c, string

I have no idea, why my program crashes, when passing a string to a function. I'm quite cerain it should be working. :/

```
void add_person(node **head, char name[MAXDL], char surn[MAXDL]);

int main()
{
int i;
char nm[MAXDL], sn[MAXDL];
node **head = NULL;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    scanf("%s", nm);
    scanf("%s", sn);
    add_person(*head, nm, sn); //IN THAT LINE THE PROBLEM OCCURS
}
//...

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}


void add_person(node **head, char name[MAXDL], char surn[MAXDL])
{
//body
}
```

The purpose of the programme is to create a list and add three people to it.
I've commented the line, where sth is not right. 
Debugger:
"Exception thrown at 0x00D91A54 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Well, I honestly have no idea what is going wrong in there. :(

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (concentrate on the "Minimal"). And "my program crashes" is no **specific** problem description. Use a debugger.

Comment: `glowa` contains NULL and you are trying to use `*glowa`. The crash has nothing to do with strings.

Comment: "Debugger: "Exception thrown at 0x00D91A54 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000." Does not look like a debugger message. If you do not know what a debugger is, search for the term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following changes.

```
void add_person(node **head, char name[MAXDL], char surn[MAXDL]);

int main()
{
int i;
char nm[MAXDL], sn[MAXDL];
node *head = NULL; // <-------------- **head -> *head
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    scanf("%s", nm);
    scanf("%s", sn);
    add_person(&head, nm, sn); <----------- *head -> &head
}
//...

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}


void add_person(node **head, char name[MAXDL], char surn[MAXDL])
{
// assuming that you will allocate node in this function like so
*head = malloc(sizeof(node)); <------------- allocation here?
}
```

Comment: void add_person(node **head, char name[MAXDL], char surn[MAXDL]) <-------------- shouldn't I change **head to *head in here as well, then?

Comment: No. Because the function needs to be passed `node**` and `&head` is `node**`.

Answer (score 0):

You assign `head` to be `NULL` then you dereference. This causes the crash. You could just pass in `head` instead of `*head` and it would not crash. However, you would be passing in `NULL`, which I imagine is not what you are trying to do.

`NULL` is the address 0x00000000, which is why it says you are trying to read 0x00000000. You never want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the body of `add_person`, try:

1. Change `node **head = NULL;` to `node *head = NULL;`
2. Change `add_person(*head, nm, sn);` to `add_person(&head, nm, sn);`